# How can i set mapping with annotations to get less queries than now?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, many-to-many

How can i set mapping with annotations to get less queries than now?
I need only reading data.

```
...
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Address address;
private Set<Office> offices = new HashSet<Office>();
private Map<Office, Position> positions = new HashMap<Office, Position>();
private Office office;
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Office.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "H_OFFICE_EMPLOYEE",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "OFFICE_ID")})
    public Set getOffices() {
        return offices;
    }

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Position.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "H_OFFICE_EMPLOYEE",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "POSITION_ID")})
    @MapKeyManyToMany(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "OFFICE_ID"), targetEntity = Office.class)
    public Map getPositions() {
        return positions;
    }
    ...
```

I get next queries in console when get 1 employee (and his address,city,country,companies where he work, employees count in every office (where he working)):

```
Hibernate: select employee0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as...
Hibernate: select address0_.ADDRESS_ID as...
Hibernate: select offices0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as...
Hibernate: select positions0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as...
Hibernate: select employees0_.OFFICE_ID as...
Hibernate: select offices0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as...
Hibernate: select employees0_.OFFICE_ID as...
Hibernate: select positions0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as...
```

What i must change in my mapping to get less queries?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the fetch type to join as explained in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-fetching).

Comment: To test i add @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) after @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Office.class),
But queries count remain the same. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It should work (even if I use JPQL and fetch join queries in most situation where this is relevant). I will take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: I tested it rebuilding your data structure and it worked as expected, fetching everything with one statement. I don't know what the problem with this actual code and setting is. Note beside: Most of the time it may even be a better idea to have more statements and less join-everything. But it is possible in general.